# How can I rerun part of a bash script until a condition is true?

Tags: bash, loops

I have this code below:

```
file=$inputfile
prefix=$prefixPath
while read line
do
    sourcePath=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d,)
    var1=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d,)
    var2="$(echo -e "${var1}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

    destinationPath=$(echo "$prefix$var2")

    echo $sourcePath
    echo $datalakePath

# Upload data from specific path to DataLake.
az dls fs upload --account eanpdlstore2 --source-path $sourcePath  --
destination-path $datalakePath --overwrite
  done < $file

 #Download data from DataLake to local temp dir
 az dls fs download --account eanpdlstore2 --destination-path $temp_path --
 source-path $datalakePath --overwrite

#Tar the whole dir and calculate the sha1sum
tar czf sourceFolder.tar.gz $sourceFolderPath | sha1sum > checksum1.txt
tar czf tempFolder.tar.gz $temp_path | sha2sum > checksum2.txt

 if diff -qr checksum1.txt checksum2.txt != True:
 then
     loop until check is matched.
 else:
     echo 'checksum matched'
```

I want to check if checksum is matched if not i want to loop again code, what is the best way to write it. Can someone help?

Comment: BTW -- consider running this through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: beyond that, though -- if it doesn't match the first time, why would it ever match in a subsequent test? So I don't see what the value of the loop is in the first place.

Comment: BTW, if you only want to know if two files match at all, `diff` is a much slower tool than `cmp`. `if cmp -s file1 file2; then echo "Files match"; else echo "Files don't match; waiting before retry"; sleep 1; fi`

Comment: ...note that there's no need for `!= True` -- `if foo` branches on whether the exit status of `foo` is zero or nonzero, so the comparison to the pertinent truthy value (`0`) is implicit.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy, I'm looping it because while upload or downloading some data might get lost so if it fails i'm uploading it and downloading it to check again. And also thanks for suggesting cmp over diff.

Comment: so if that's the case, you'd want to put the code you want to rerun inside the loop.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes but not sure how to do that.

Comment: BTW, note that `while read line` can be changed to `while IFS=, read sourcePath var1; do var2=${var1//[[:space:]]/}` to avoid all the `cut` and `tr` usage.

Comment: umm... copy-and-paste the code to be inside the loop?

Comment: BTW, how many lines of input do you expect (for the outer loop reading from `$file`)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i can do that but that makes the code more lines and duplicated so looking for other way, and thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: It's only duplicate if you keep a separate copy *outside* the loop as well. Why would you do that? You have only one copy, and it's inside the loop -> there you are.

Comment: So, when you say "loop", you want to jump back and redo exactly how much of the process? Do you redo the `fs upload` and onward?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, can you please show how to do that ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes I want to go back to fs upload and do it from there to comparision.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thank you so much.

Comment: BTW, in general, you should avoid the `-e` argument to `echo` unless you have a very specific reason for using it. (Usually, when you *think* you need to use it, you're better off with `printf` instead -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the logic to run the download *into the loop*, so it implicitly gets rerun for as long as the loop does.

The below is missing some pieces that were also missing in the original question (for example, `temp_path` is never set, and content is never moved into `destinationPath`), but it should provide a solid place to start.

The various `|| continue` bits ensure that we go back to the `until` and retry the loop if we fail.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o pipefail  # if any part of a pipeline fails, consider the entire command to fail

file=$1          # input file
prefix=$2        # destination prefix

while IFS=, read -r sourcePath var1; do
  var2=${var1//[[:space:]]/}
  destinationPath="$prefix$var2"
  checksum1=
  checksum2=

  until [[ $checksum1 && $checksum2 && "$checksum1" = "$checksum2" ]]; do
    # Upload data from specific path to DataLake.
    az dls fs upload --account eanpdlstore2 --source-path "$sourcePath" --destination-path "$datalakePath" --overwrite || continue

    #Download data from DataLake to local temp dir
    az dls fs download --account eanpdlstore2 --destination-path "$temp_path" --source-path "$datalakePath" --overwrite || continue

    #Tar the whole dir and calculate the sha1sum
    checksum1=$(tar -czf sourceFolder.tar.gz "$sourceFolderPath" | sha1sum) || checksum1=
    checksum2=$(tar -czf tempFolder.tar.gz "$temp_path" | sha1sum) || checksum2=
  done </dev/null ## safety: stop anything here from consuming lines from the input file
done <"$file"
```